# How do you make the terminal $PS1 indent when wrapping to a second line?

Tags: bash, word-wrap, ps1

I'm trying to make my PS1 more readable and one issue I'm currently having is that my file prompts are too long. I don't want to shorten them however, since that would mean loss of exactitude.

My solution so far is to simply send the prompt after the file location to a new line. But this still doesn't look clean, as the file location is cut off mid filename and then continued underneath the username.

What I'm trying to do is have it look something like this in the end:

```
gingerbread: ~/file/file/file/file/file/
              file/file/file/file.txt
```

But what I have right now is this:

```
gingerbread: ~/file/file/file/file/file/fil
e/file/file/file.txt
```

N.B. I already have a function doing the name prompt, cos I'm an idiot and made the username show up in all the colors of the rainbow... Here's the code for that in case it helps:

```
fancyName() 
{
    PERSPS='';
    NAME='gingerbread';
    LENGTHNAME=${#NAME};
    for i in `seq 1 $LENGTHNAME`;
        do
            NUM=$((($i % 8) + 30));
            PERSPS="$PERSPS\[\033[01;$NUM";
            PERSPS+="m\]${NAME:$i-1:1}";
        done
    PERSPS="$PERSPS\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\[$\] ";
}
```

I then use `$PERSPS` as the `$PS1`. The whole thing just cycles through colors basically.

How do I control where the prompt wraps and where it wraps to?

Thanks in advance,
*-Me.*

Comment: Not a solution, but super useful: https://scriptim.github.io/bash-prompt-generator/.  You might find a solution using that tool.

Comment: Thanks. I think I actually solved this myself eventually. The space at the end of PERSPS was the problem. It didn't dissappear when wrapping and messed everything up.
I will look into the link you sent though.

Comment: FYI, bash does not require `;` at end of lines.  `;` is usually used to separate two commands on the same line.